# How to forward traffic from LAN Network to WAN network?

Tags: networking, routes, traffic, chain

____________________________________________________________________________________________General information:

---

Daisy chain network
ubuntu 22.04

Network id: 192.168.39.0/26 and 192.168.39.64/26

goal is the router and
node should get internet through gateway.

gateway have 2 NIC.

- one NAT
- one internal network (LAN1)

router have 2 NIC

- one internal network (LAN1)
- internal network (LAN2)

end node have one NIC

- internal network (LAN2)

all 3 devices can talk to each other

LAN Segments are correct

firewall on all 3 device is inactive

all 3 device belong in one network

What am I doing wrong in configuring Daisy chain network between gateway, router, and end node?

configured following things on **Gateway**:

gig0/0/1 ip add 192.168.39.1/26 (Lan 1)

default route to Gig0/0/0

masqurade to Gig0/0/0

configured following things on **router**:

gig0/0/0 ip address: 192.168.39.2/26 (LAN 1)

gig0/0/1 ip addresses: 192.168.39.65/26 (Lan 2)

allowed packet forwarding

default route to 192.168.39.1

configured following things on **end node**:

Fa0 ip add 192.168.39.66/26(Lan 2)

default route to: 192.168.39.66 /26

Answer (score 0):

On end node you need default route to: 192.168.39.65 /26